# Approximation of Rydberg Equation at Very Large $n$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, calculus, approximations

I have been working the Rydberg equation with large $n$ to see how quantum systems when they become very large are functionally identical to classical systems. The problem I'm facing is trying to approximate the energy between two states when $n \gg 1$.

I've gotten up to the point of
$$\frac{1}{n^2(1+1/n)^2} - \frac{1}{n^2}$$
I'm stuck on the first term and have seen elsewhere people approximate this to
$$\frac{1}{n^2}\left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right)$$
I'm unsure how this approximation follows. I would really like to see the steps for this in case I need to use it in the future.

Comment: It is math. For small $\delta$, $1/(1-\delta) \approx 1+\delta$. And $(1+\delta)^2 \approx 1+2\delta$. The first terms in series expansions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straightforward application of the [binomial approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_approximation), which says that when $|ax| \ll 1$,
$$
(1 + x)^a \approx 1 + a x.
$$
In this case, we can identify $x = 1/n \ll 1$, and $a = -2$, which means that
$$
\frac{1}{(1 + 1/n)^2} \approx 1 - 2 \frac{1}{n}.
$$

Comment: I was getting stuck on the substitution $x=1/n$. Thank you so much!